# Error JMSCMQ1049 in JMS message received in listener - IBM MQ

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms

I'm creating a Listener with Java 17, driver IBM MQ Jakarta.client version 9.3.3.0, Spring Boot 3.
I would like to know if anyone has experienced this. I receive a message that I cannot deal with, and I would like the client to remove it from the queue.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCMQ1049: The character set '1252(windows-1252) Unmappable Action: REPORT, Unmappable Replacement: 63, spaceByte: 32' cannot convert some or all of the string '[B@42c3bd63'
```

I updated version driver MQ and my expectation that this message finally it is consumed.